# Is there a way to assign values to a data frame in a for-loop?

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, assign

I want to assign values to a dataframe using a for-loop which loops trough different rows in a data-frame.

I tried to assign my needed variable names, which are changing in each iteration, to some values and afterwards put those values together in a dataframe, which did not work

```
banks <- read.csv("banks_csv.csv", sep = ";", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
banks<-data.frame(banks)

for (row in 1:nrow(banks)){
bank = banks[row, "Company"]

reviews <- read.csv(paste(bank, "_cleaned.csv", sep = ""))
reviews$X = NULL
reviews_summary <- reviews %>% 
group_by(Year_Quarter) %>%     
    summarise(rat_gen = mean(rat_general, na.rm = TRUE), 
              CV = mean(rat_CV, na.rm = TRUE), 
              WL = mean(rat_WL, na.rm = TRUE), 
              CO = mean(rat_CO, na.rm = TRUE), 
              CB = mean(rat_CB, na.rm = TRUE), 
              SM = mean(rat_SM, na.rm = TRUE)) 

nam <- paste("general_", bank, sep = "")
assign(nam, reviews_summary$rat_gen)

nam <- paste("CV_", bank, sep = "")
assign(nam, reviews_summary$CV)

nam <- paste("WL_", bank, sep = "")
assign(nam, reviews_summary$WL)

nam <- paste("CO_", bank, sep = "")
as.list(nam, reviews_summary$CO)

nam <- paste("CB_", bank, sep = "")
as.list(nam, reviews_summary$CB)

nam <- paste("SM_", bank, sep = "")
as.list(nam, reviews_summary$SM)

df <- data.frame(paste("general_", bank, sep = ""), paste("CV_", bank, sep = ""), paste("WL_", bank, sep = ""), paste("CO_", bank, sep = ""), paste("CB_", bank, sep = ""), paste("SM_", bank, sep = ""))
}
```

EDIT: I would like to have only one data.frame, where each iteration adds 6 columns, instead of generating one dataframe for each iteration.

Comment: Hi, I don't really understand what your desired output should look like.
Do you want the same values as is `reviews_summary` but with different column names?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! What I am looking for would be something similar, but instead of generating a new data frame for each iteration, I would like to have only one data.frame, where each iteration adds 6 columns, sorry for the bad description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this is what you are looking for. You can rename columns using the `rename` function:

```
for (row in 1:nrow(banks)){
  bank = banks[row, "Company"]
  reviews <- read.csv(paste(bank, "_cleaned.csv", sep = ""))

  df_bank <- reviews %>% 
    group_by(Year_Quarter) %>%     
    summarise(general = mean(rat_general, na.rm = TRUE), 
              CV = mean(rat_CV, na.rm = TRUE), 
              WL = mean(rat_WL, na.rm = TRUE), 
              CO = mean(rat_CO, na.rm = TRUE), 
              CB = mean(rat_CB, na.rm = TRUE), 
              SM = mean(rat_SM, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
    rename_at(-1, ~paste0(.x, "_", bank)) %>% 
    as.data.frame()

  df <- cbind(df, df_bank)
 }
```

Note that you have to initialize `df`to have the right number of rows before you start the loop.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! What I am looking for would be something similar, but instead of generating a new data frame for each iteration, I would like to have only one data.frame, where each iteration adds 6 columns, sorry for the bad description

Comment: Perfect, that was exactly what I am looking for, thanks a lot